# TIdUDPClient.ReceiveBuffer with no delay

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

Using `TIdUDPClient`, my app continuously sends audio data via UDP to another PC running a `TIdUDPServer`, which is working well.

Currently, there is no return communication required, but I'm considering a method to ask for a missing packet to be resent. This will be very rare, perhaps once an hour or less.

I'm confused as to what `ReceiveTimeout` value to use so that `ReceiveBuffer()` will not wait at all if there is nothing in the receive buffer.  I've read all the documentation on `IdTimeoutDefault` but nowhere does it say what a timeout of -1 actually does.  Should I use 0?

Also, currently I'm using `SendBuffer()` with an IP and port address every time. Do I need to use `Connect()` instead before I can receive data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a timeout in Indy is set to `IdTimeoutDefault` (-1), it gets treated as `IdTimeoutInfinite` (-2). So yes, if you want `ReceiveBuffer()` to not wait, use a timeout of 0.

UDP is connection-less, so you do not need to call `Connect()` to receive packets. If you omit it, you can receive packets from any peer that sends to your socket's bound IP/Port. Using `Connect()` allows you to accept packets only from a specific peer IP/Port, packets received from anywhere else will simply be ignored by the OS.

`Connect()` also allows you to set a specific peer IP/Port where subsequent sends will go to, so you don't have to specify the peer on every packet.

Comment: My app actually sends the data to up to 4 IP/Port destinations (multicast) doing 4 separate SendBuffer commands. In that case, would I need 4 separate TIdUDPClient instances to know which peer IP requested the resend?  Currently I use just the one.

Comment: No, you would simply use 
 1 `TIdUDPClient` and not `Connect()` it so reads will tell you which peer is sending. But why are you using separate sends per peer with multicast? The whole point of multicast is that you send 1 time to 1 group IP/port and it gets delivered to any peer who subscribes to the group. You should use `TIdIPMCastServer` for sending multicast data.